# categorial clusters with colors not preserved at any scale

Tags: qgis, clustering, expression

I am using `@cluster_color` expression and `@cluster_size` expression to built a categorical map with QGIS.

I don't really understand why clusters doesn't preserve categories at all scales. Everything is "middle age" (red) at regional scale.

[image]

[image]

[image]